# Sarpa Dosha Nivarana Mantra in Mahabaratha

Tags: mahabharata, mantras, identification-request

The following is Sarpa Dosha Nivarana Mantra.

> Anantho Vasukee Seshaha Padmanaabhascha Kambalaha Sankhapaalo
>   Dhaatharaastraha Takshaka Kaaliyasthatha Ethaani Navanaamaani
>   Nagaanaam cha Mahaathmanaam Saayamkaale pateth nityam praathakaale

Is this mantra present in Mahabharata?

If it is, who said this mantra to whom and why?